# How to grant Admin Permissions to User Account in Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, permissions, administrator

Does anyone know how to give a user in Snow Leopard administrator permissions?

Concerning Josh K. Answer:

I made sure that I do have this checked, and I do. However, the OS keeps telling me for certain files, that I need permission from the administrator. I run into this problem when I try to edit files in my MAMP directory. (Specifically a configuration file)

Comment: Someone upvote this, I'm outta votes.

Comment: done. why @Josh?

Comment: Well at the time I was outta votes for the day.

Answer (score 7):

You mean "root"?

I think you intend to give an administrator permission to a user.
Simply, 
from System Preferences > Accounts > Then select "Allow user to administer this computer".  You will need admin privileges yourself to set this for someone else.

[Here is the documentation from Apple on creating new users](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.5/en/8235.html).

[image]

Take it easy :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Open up System Preferences and select "Accounts" under "System." Unlock the panel if necessary, then select the user that you wish to promote to Administrator status and check the box that says "Allow user to administer this computer."

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: I made sure that I do have this checked, and I do. However, the OS keeps telling me for certain files, that I need permission from the administrator. I run into this problem when I try to edit files in my MAMP directory. (Specifically a configuration file)

Comment: You may have to take ownership of those files. Select the file and "Get Info" and see who owns it and what the permissions are.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to activate root user, some files only can be deleted with root user privileges.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1528

Comment: You don't need `root` account. If you need more privileges, then use `sudo`.